# Building a customized, fuzzy and multiple Vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

Ok so, twice a month I receive a large file of about 100 rows, which contains 4 columns:

Building name - value - county - state

I´ve to complete 2 other columns based on a master list that have thousands of entries.

I want to produce something very similar to this fabulous add-in (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011), but a bit simpler and that I could use at work without problems.

What I need to do is the following:

In order to match my input with the master file, I know the county and state must match, but then, the building names can change a bit in each file for the same building (ie "John Miller #34" can be "Miller, John 34 A"), and that the values may vary but not too much.

Based on that, I want to bring from the master to my file, all the entries that may match each of my rows, filtering by County and State first, and then by similarity in name and value.

Could you please share your thoughts on how you´d approach this?

I know this is not a simple thing, but anything may help!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for you, the vlookup "fuzzy logic" is nowhere near reliable for your purpose (see the comment on my answer below for details), and you won't have any indicator as to whether the returned result is accurate or not.

It's possible to get 100% of what you want through some heavy coding in a user-defined function, but this is probably well beyond your comfort zone.

A clunky solution, although somewhat easy to explain and adopt, is to create an "identity column" for every unique scenario that can occur.  So, for example:

[image: identityCol]

Then you can import your master sheet and add the same identity column to the left, and perform your vlookup.  When a new configuration is added you can just add that to the master list and it will populate in your imported file in future instances.

That said, if you are interested in learning, there have been many people who have walked in your shows and felt your pain.  You may want to indulge in this:

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/195635-fuzzy-matching-new-version-plus-explanation.html

Because what you are truly requesting is an algorithm.  It's not a simple thing, but it's very possible.  And if you take the time to learn you not only solve your immediate problem, but make yourself marketable as an Excel wiz.  Good luck!

Comment: Passing TRUE for the last parameter of a vlookup does not perform "a best-guess" or "return any old value it deems fit". It assumes a sorted list and searches the column until it finds a value that should sort after or equal to the search value. It is not doing any similarity check, only an alphabetical comparison. Also, "always use false" isn't right either. TRUE is useful for things like tax tables and data tables grouped by date that skip days just to name a couple uses.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll revise my answer.  In my experiences, which do not include things like tax tables and _do_ include unsorted lists (as in the situation above) it will return a value that isn't reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use wildcards to try and match on the primary identifier within the name. from your example, that might be "Miller", for example.